# How do I grab data from a many-to-many relationship? (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just successfully set up a many-to-many relationship between BlogPosts and Topics in Entity Framework code first approach.  So there are a list of topics ("CSS", "HTML", "ASP.NET") that a BlogPost can have many of and vice versa.  So currently I had EF create 3 tables, the middle table being the id of both the BlogPost and the Topic itself.

Now I am in the Razor view of my homepage.

```
@model MvcBlog.Models.MyModel

@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    <div class="blogpost">
        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</h2>
        <div class="post_info">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.DateCreated)<span class="right">Blog</span></div>
        <p>@Html.Raw(post.Content)</p>
        <div class="post_close">
            <span class="left">
                ***********************
            </span>
            <span class="right"><img src="Content/images/comment.jpg" alt="" /> 0 comments</span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

All of the above works just fine, but I want to replace the *** with the topics associated with this particular post.  I can't seem to figure this out.  Do I have to pass the model differently from the controller?  Currently I am passing the entire DB to this page as it will be using various info from different tables.  I am just lost on this one.  Any help would be really appreciated! (Obviously I want to do something similar with comments)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started on the recommended course of action. Your view model will be a normal class:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
   public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
   public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you populate what you need for the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   // assuming entity framework
   List<PostViewModel> posts = (from p in context.Set<Post>()
                                select new PostViewModel {
                                   Title = p.Title,
                                   DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                                   Topics = p.Topics
                                }).ToList();
   return View(posts);
}
```

And in your view

```
@model List<PostViewModel>

@foreach(Post post in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Title)

    @foreach(Topic topic in post.Topics)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I am starting to understand.  What is "context" here in "context.Set<Post>()"?  Context doesn't exist for me, am I just ignoring something obvious?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @pjb5064. "context" is referring to DBContext of Entity Framework. I included it as an example. Basically, you have to get your data from somewhere, and the place you get it is in your controller.

Comment: okay... now I'm just getting an error everytime I try to run it (builds successfully btw) "The entity or complex type 'MvcBense.Models.BlogPost' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Nevermind... I was doing "select new Post" instead of "select new PostViewModel"... thanks for the help!  I still have so much to learn it's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no, do NOT pass the entire database to the view. You need to be abstracting your view data from your database.  Create a view model containing just the data you need for this view in the format best suited for the view to consume it.  Use your controller or model code, depending on whether you believe in fat or thin controllers, to transform the data from the database into the view model.  The whole point of MVC is separation of concerns and if you let your data model leak into the view code, you will be losing this basic idea and lose the benefits of loose coupling between the various layers.

Comment: I guess I haven't come across an example of multiple models in one controller.  Everything I have seen has been one basic function.  Could you link me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: @pjb5064 You use one view model, but that model contains all the data you need. For example, your model could be a collection of PostViewModels (or more like a PageModel that contains a page's worth of posts along with which page you're on, how many pages there are, etc). Each of these contains one post's data, including a collection of CommentModel objects representing the comments for that post. The point is that these are decoupled from your actual entities. That way your DB changes don't necessarily propagate to your view code.

Comment: Thank you.  As you can see I have much to learn.  I am 2 years out of college and had a job for a bit with just .aspx web forms doing basic things.  That job didn't work out in the end and I am forcing myself to learn MVC3 to create a blog and hopefully more.  There are many lessons to be learned here...  I appreciate you reinforcing the point of MVC and I am trying not to stray from the norm here.

Answer (score 0):

`Do I have to pass the model differently from the controller?`

Yes. Make a model specifically for the needs of your view (a view model). Fill in the correct object graphs there (which blog goes to which topic). Then pass that instantiated object into the view and reference those objects in your view.